# Can you apply an operation directly to arguments within map/reduce/filter?

Tags: python, syntax, iteration, readability

`map` and `filter` are often interchangeable with list comprehensions, but `reduce` is not so easily swapped out as `map` and `filter` (and besides, in some cases I still prefer the functional syntax anyway). When you need to operate on the arguments themselves, though, I find myself going through syntactical gymnastics and eventually have to write entire functions to maintain readability.

I'll use `map` to keep the illustration unit-test simple, but please keep in mind that real-life use-cases might be harder to express as a list comprehension.

I've found two messy ways to go about it, but nothing I would ever actually use.

```
[afunc(*i) for i in aniter] == map(afunc, *zip(*aniter))
[afunc(*i) for i in aniter] == map(lambda i: apply(afunc, i), aniter)
```

Is there any pithy, elegant way to express the right hand side of these expressions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) for tools that will make your life easier.

For example, the code you posted is already available as [`itertools.starmap`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap).

```
itertools.starmap(afunc, aniter)
```

From the documentation:

> Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments obtained from the iterable. Used instead of imap() when argument parameters are already grouped in tuples from a single iterable (the data has been “pre-zipped”). The difference between imap() and starmap() parallels the distinction between function(a,b) and function(*c). Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def starmap(function, iterable):
>    # starmap(pow, [(2,5), (3,2), (10,3)]) --> 32 9 1000
>    for args in iterable:
>        yield function(*args)
> ```

There are also tons over other goodies hidden in `itertools`, so I recommend you read through the documentation to see if there is anything else there that you can use. The [recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) section also show ways that you can use the functions available in `itertools` to solve a variety of problems. Even if you can't find a recipe that solves your exact requirements, it's likely that you can use some of the ideas demonstrated as a source of inspiration.

Comment: Nice, I use itertools all the time, but for some reason it didn't occur to me to look there for this.